# Transaction details not getting after the payment in paypal sandbox

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

[image]Unable to get the transaction details after the payment even after setting the IPN  as well as the return url in the payment details. The transaction details are not getting into the success page: [Image of completed transaction page in sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aVcN.png)

Here is the complete source code where I have taken 
https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-subscriptions-payment-gateway-integration-php

Comment: Your question needs to be more focused. What is the specific thing that is failing? Please show a runtime request+response of an API call, for example, or something else that demonstrates an unexpected behavior.

`45056696NJ790240K` appears to be a completed sender/buyer-side subscription payment in sandbox that you could get the details of if you request it correctly.  However, you more likely want to work with the receiver/seller-side transaction ID, which will be a different ID for the same transaction.

Comment: The transaction details https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aVcN.png is not returning to merchant i.e success page instead of "your payment was unsuccessful" I need the transaction details on success.php page

Comment: Sorry, you just described the same thing again, and it's too general. It doesn't tell me which exact piece of the underlying process is failing for you in an unexpected way, thus leading to that "unsuccessful" message.